# How do you escape inverted commas in a BAT file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to set a variable:

> set pathJDK=%pathDrive%\"Program Files"\Java\jdk\

inside a .bat file but when I execute it, then it responds with an error saying: "Cannot find jdk at C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk\"

I've also tried putting inverted commas on each end of the entire path but same problem.

For some reason it fails with spaces and when you use inverted commas then it fails to ignore them and only use them to escape the spaces.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining `Program Files` as variable:

> SET PROGRAMFILES=Program Files

And then

> set pathJDK=%pathDrive%\%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk\

Answer (score 1):

```
set "pathJDK=%pathDrive%\Program Files\Java\jdk\"
```

or just:

```
set pathJDK=%pathDrive%\Program Files\Java\jdk\
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the pathJDK variable without quotes

```
set pathJDK=%pathDrive%\Program Files\Java\jdk
```

but then, when calling other batch file or external program with command that depends on pathJDK variable, you need to use quotes. Like that:

```
"%pathJDK%\SomeProg.exe"
```

or

```
call "%pathJDK%\SomeScript.cmd"
```